# Finding energy bands of trimerized 1D periodic crystal in second quantization formalism

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian-formalism, crystals, second-quantization

I am trying to figure out the energy bands of a trimerized 1D periodic crystal model. Suppose we have three atom types per unit cell $A,B,C$, and we have the Hamiltonian

$$H = - \sum_j c_{j+1, A}^\dagger c_{j,C} + c_{j, C}^\dagger c_{j+1,A}$$

where $c_{j,\sigma}^\dagger$ and $c_{j,\sigma}$ are the creation and annihilation operators (respectively) of electrons at cell-position $x_j$ in atoms of type $\sigma$. In this case, I just use a Fourier transformation to obtain

$$H = -2 \sum_k \cos(k \Delta) c_{k,A}^\dagger c_{k,C} = \sum_k \epsilon_k c_{k,A}^\dagger c_{k,C}$$

where $\Delta$ is the distance between the atom of type $A$ and the neighboring atom of type $C$.

But, I get one band only. Should I get more bands like with the dimerized model?

Comment: Your Hamiltonian contains only two types of atoms. In addition, your Fourier transformed Hamiltonian is not diagonal.

Comment: How do I fix this? I am confused by having more than one type for the same $k$. Is this what is making it not diagonal? Also, it is supposed to be like this in the problem I am trying to solve with just two types of atoms in the Hamiltonian

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is an issue with the Hamiltonian, since it contains couplings only between two types of atoms (A and C). A more general Hamiltonian would be
$$H = - \sum_j\sum_{\sigma,\sigma'}\left[t_{\sigma\sigma'}c_{j+1,\sigma}^\dagger c_{j,\sigma'} + t_{\sigma\sigma'}^*c_{j,\sigma'}^\dagger c_{j+1,\sigma}\right].$$
The hopping constant $t_{\sigma\sigma'}$ can be taken real, if there is no magnetic field.
Then, in order to diagnonalize this Hamiltonian we could use conjecture
$$c_{k,\alpha} \propto \sum_j e^{ikj}\sum_\sigma x_{\alpha\sigma}c_{j,\sigma}.$$
Exponent $e^{ikj}$ should take care of the spatial dependence, leaving us to diagonalize a 3-by-3 matrix, whose eigenvectors I labeled by $\alpha$.

**Alternative approach**
One could try to solve this problem in two steps:

1. One performs the Fourier transform, obtaining
   $$H = - \sum_k\sum_{\sigma,\sigma'}2\cos(k\Delta)t_{\sigma\sigma'}c_{k,\sigma}^\dagger c_{k,\sigma'}.$$
2. One then has to diagonalize the 3-by-3 Hamiltonian for each $k$.

Comment: That is the same Hamiltonian though

Comment: You have only $t_{AC}=1$ and all other amplitudes equal to zero. At maximum your Hamiltonian is diatomic, not triatomic as you say.

Comment: What is $x_{\alpha \sigma}$ in your expression for $c_{k,\alpha}$?

Comment: The coefficients which express band states as combinations of states on different atoms.

Comment: You can do it in two steps, as I added in the answer.

Comment: In the case $t_{AC} = 1 = t_{CA}$ and $t_{\sigma \sigma'} = 0$ for any other $\sigma, \sigma'$. Should I diagonalize $\begin{pmatrix}0& 0& -2\cos(k\Delta) \\ 0&0&0 \\ -2\cos(k\Delta) &0&0\end{pmatrix}$ for each $k$?

Comment: In this case you can ignore atom B, since it is not coupled to anything. So you need only to diagonalize the 2-by-2 matrix and you will have two bands. You will have $c_{k,\pm} = (c_{k,A} \pm c_{k,C})/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: But if I intend to do it the alternative way.